# iOS simulator crashes in Xcode 6

Tags: device, boot, xcode6

I'm running Xcode6-Beta and When I try running up the iOS simulator I get this error:

[image]

It was working fine up until this point.  I've tried restarting Xcode and rebooting my Mac but the issue is still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Resolved my issue by removing the device from the list of devices in iOS simulator, restarting Xcode and the simulator, adding the deleted devices back to iOS simulator, again restarting Xcode and the simulator.

Comment: This stuff is beta quality, it crashes. :(

Comment: You could try Reset simulator content, I had this warning several times too.